# SQLiteException: near "FROM": syntax error multiple Joins

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

Can anyone see if there is an error in my query here, it's my first attempt at multiple Joins, below is the logcat error. Thanks in advance

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "FROM": syntax error
> (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1]): , while compiling: SELECT SUM(A.quantity),
> A.ingredient, A.recipe, B.ingredient_type, B.measurement_name, C.id,
> D.plan_name, FROM QUANTITY AS A JOIN INGREDIENTS AS B ON A.ingredient
> = B.ingredient_name JOIN PLAN_RECIPES AS C ON A.recipe = C.recipe_name  JOIN MEAL_PLAN AS D ON C.id = D.plan_recipe GROUP BY A.ingredient
> WHERE D.plan_name LIKE ?

**Code**

```
    public void loadIngredient() {
    shopList.clear();
    db = (new DatabaseManager(this).getWritableDatabase());
    String RECIPE_SEARCH = " SELECT SUM(A.quantity), A.ingredient, A.recipe, B.ingredient_type, B.measurement_name, C.id, D.plan_name, " +
            "FROM " + DatabaseManager.TABLE_QUANTITY + " AS A JOIN " + DatabaseManager.TABLE_INGREDIENTS +
            " AS B ON A.ingredient = B.ingredient_name" + " JOIN " + DatabaseManager.TABLE_PLAN_RECIPES + " AS C ON A.recipe = C.recipe_name " +
            " JOIN " + DatabaseManager.TABLE_MEAL_PLAN + " AS D ON C.id = D.plan_recipe GROUP BY A.ingredient";
    String selectQuery = "";
    selectQuery = RECIPE_SEARCH + " WHERE D.plan_name LIKE ?";
    c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[]{"%" + search + "%"});
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Shopping_List shopping_list = new Shopping_List();
            shopping_list.setQuantity(c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("quantity")));
            shopping_list.setIngredient_name(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ingredient_name")));
            shopping_list.setIngredient_type(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ingredient_type")));
            shopping_list.setMeasurement_name(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("measurement_name")));
            shopList.add(shopping_list);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
        c.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Remove the `,` after `D.plan_name` in the string `RECIPE_SEARCH`.

Comment: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "WHERE": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1]): , while compiling: SELECT SUM(A.quantity), A.ingredient, A.recipe, B.ingredient_type, B.measurement_name, C.id, D.plan_name FROM QUANTITY AS A JOIN INGREDIENTS AS B ON A.ingredient = B.ingredient_name JOIN PLAN_RECIPES AS C ON A.recipe = C.recipe_name  JOIN MEAL_PLAN AS D ON C.id = D.plan_recipe GROUP BY A.ingredient WHERE D.plan_name LIKE ?

Comment: Put the WHERE clause before the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 34 rows, 7 columns.

Comment: See my answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems in your code.

The 1st is a comma that you must remove after `D.plan_name` inside the variable `RECIPE_SEARCH` right before the `FROM` clause.

The 2nd is the `WHERE` clause that must precede the `GROUP BY` clause.

The 3d is that you must alias the column `SUM(A.quantity)` that is returned by your query so you can retrieve it by that alias, say `quantity`.

The 4th is that there is no column `ingredient_name` returned by your query, but I assume this is the column `A.ingredient` which should be aliased to `ingredient_name`.

So change to this:

```
public void loadIngredient() {
    shopList.clear();
    db = (new DatabaseManager(this).getWritableDatabase());
    String RECIPE_SEARCH = 
        "SELECT SUM(A.quantity) quantity, A.ingredient ingredient_name, A.recipe, B.ingredient_type, B.measurement_name, C.id, D.plan_name " +
        "FROM " + DatabaseManager.TABLE_QUANTITY + " AS A JOIN " + DatabaseManager.TABLE_INGREDIENTS + " AS B ON A.ingredient = B.ingredient_name " + 
        "JOIN " + DatabaseManager.TABLE_PLAN_RECIPES + " AS C ON A.recipe = C.recipe_name " +
        "JOIN " + DatabaseManager.TABLE_MEAL_PLAN + " AS D ON C.id = D.plan_recipe " +
        "WHERE D.plan_name LIKE ? GROUP BY A.ingredient";   
    c = db.rawQuery(RECIPE_SEARCH, new String[]{"%" + search + "%"});

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Shopping_List shopping_list = new Shopping_List();
            shopping_list.setQuantity(c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("quantity")));
            shopping_list.setIngredient_name(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ingredient_name")));
            shopping_list.setIngredient_type(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ingredient_type")));
            shopping_list.setMeasurement_name(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("measurement_name")));
            shopList.add(shopping_list);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();
    db.close();
}
```

Also, your query returns columns that you don't use in the loop, which I did not remove, by you may remove them.

Comment: I'm still getting Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

Comment: Check again the column names/aliases. They must be exactly the same a the ones inside the loop: `quantity, ingredient_name, ingredient_type, measurement_name`. You can remove 1 each time to spot which one is not the same.

Comment: I can't see any issues with these

Comment: Did you copy the code as it is? Did you try by removing 1 column at a time from the loop? first remove `shopping_list.setQuantity(c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("quantity")));` and run. Then remove `shopping_list.setIngredient_name(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ingredient_name")));` etc

Comment: Yep it still does it, removing each line one by one.

Comment: Log the value of RECIPE_SEARCH  and post it here.

Comment: 2020-10-03 18:00:00.357 13571-13571/com.stu54259.plan2cook D/Search query: SELECT SUM(A.ingredient_quantity) ingredient_quantity, A.ingredient, A.recipe, B.ingredient_type, B.measurement_name, C.id, D.plan_name FROM QUANTITY AS A JOIN INGREDIENTS AS B ON A.ingredient = B.ingredient_name JOIN PLAN_RECIPES AS C ON A.recipe = C.recipe_name JOIN MEAL_PLAN AS D ON C.id = D.plan_recipe WHERE D.plan_name LIKE ? GROUP BY A.ingredient

Comment: Why did you change the alias to `ingredient_quantity`? In this line: `shopping_list.setQuantity(c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("quantity")));` you are trying to retrieve it withe the name `quantity`.

Comment: Also you did not set the alias of `A.ingredient` to `ingredient_name`.

Comment: Confused was changing as A.quantity should be ingredient_quantity

Comment: 2020-10-03 18:06:41.006 17209-17209/com.stu54259.plan2cook D/Search query: SELECT SUM(A.ingredient_quantity) quantity, A.ingredient ingredient_name, A.recipe, B.ingredient_type, B.measurement_name, C.id, D.plan_name FROM QUANTITY AS A JOIN INGREDIENTS AS B ON A.ingredient = B.ingredient_name JOIN PLAN_RECIPES AS C ON A.recipe = C.recipe_name JOIN MEAL_PLAN AS D ON C.id = D.plan_recipe WHERE D.plan_name LIKE ? GROUP BY A.ingredient

Comment: That was no error but has not displayed as it should has displayed com.stu54259.plan2cook.Model.Shopping_list@5cb7482 and this continues with varying end codes

Comment: Your `loadIngredient()` does not display anything. It just fills the list with the rows of the table. Somewhere else in your code you are trying to display the list and there you should search for the problem.

Comment: So its not the list? Just the recycler view?

Comment: The method `loadIngredient()` has nothing to do with the RecyclerView where I guess you display the items of the list. Probably after the call to `loadIngredient()` you will display the items of the list in the RecyclerView.

Comment: That's the idea yes, just not happening the recyclerview adpter i'm using is almost identical as another I use and that one works fine.

Comment: I don't know about that. But *almost identical* is usually a source for problems, especially when you copy and paste code that is not properly adjusted for each case.